# Exclude old events from WP_Query with date saved in a `meta_key`

Tags: wp-query

I use the bellow template to display the first event from an ascendent list of custom post type events, created by a third party plugin. What I want is to exclude old events, displaying only the one actual, if we have one today, or the nearest. The event start date is saved in a `meta_key` with a value in the "Y-m-d" format (ex: 2017-10-27). How to accomplish this?

```
<?php

    wp_reset_query();

    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'events',
        'posts_per_page'    => 1,
        'meta_key'          => 'event_start_date',
        'order'             => 'ASC'
    );

    $featured = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($featured->have_posts()): 
        while($featured->have_posts()): $featured->the_post();

            $featured_event_start = $post->event_start_date;
            $featured_event_end = $post->event_end_date;

            if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                <div class="featured-event-outer">
                    <div class="featured-event-inner">
                        <figure><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium_large'); ?></a></figure>
                        <h3 class="featured-event-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                        <h3 class="featured-event-date">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $featured_event_start;
                                if ( $featured_event_end && $featured_event_end != $featured_event_start ) { echo ' - ' . $featured_event_end; } ?>
                            </a>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endwhile;
            else: ?>
                <!-- Placeholder content goes here -->
    <?php endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, with some help from [@jonathan-wold](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/12305/25187), I figured out how to solve my problem. In my initial code I just replaced the `$args` part, accordingly to mentioned author, and this worked like a charm. This is the code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events', // Tell WordPress which post type we want
    'orderby' => 'meta_value', // We want to organize the events by date    
    'meta_key' => 'event_start_date', // Grab the "start date" field created via "More Fields" plugin (stored in YYYY-MM-DD format)
    'order' => 'ASC', // ASC is the other option    
    'posts_per_page' => '1', // Let's show only one / the first event.
    'meta_query' => array( // WordPress has all the results, now, return only the events after today's date
        array(
            'key' => 'event_start_date', // Check the start date field
            'value' => date("Y-m-d"), // Set today's date (note the similar format)
            'compare' => '>=', // Return the ones greater than or equal to today's date
            'type' => 'DATE' // Let WordPress know we're working with date
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need something like the following:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'events',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'meta_query'        => array(
        'meta_key'          => 'event_start_date',
        'type'              => 'DATETIME',  // You can also try changing it to TIME or DATE if it doesn't work
        'meta_value'        => date( "Y-m-d" ),
        'meta_compare'      => '>',
    ),
    'order'             => 'ASC'
);
```

Comment: I already tried your solution, but it doesn't work for me, I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

Update: the code worked for me after replacing event_start_date with _event_start_date in 'meta_key'

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events', // Tell WordPress which post type we want
    'orderby' => 'meta_value', // We want to organize the events by date    
    'meta_key' => '_event_start_date', // Grab the "start date" field created via "More Fields" plugin (stored in YYYY-MM-DD format)
    'order' => 'ASC', // ASC is the other option    
    'posts_per_page' => '1', // Let's show only one / the first event.
    'meta_query' => array( // WordPress has all the results, now, return only the events after today's date
        array(
            'key' => '_event_start_date', // Check the start date field
            'value' => date("Y-m-d"), // Set today's date (note the similar format)
            'compare' => '>=', // Return the ones greater than or equal to today's date
            'type' => 'DATE' // Let WordPress know we're working with date
        )
    )
);
```