# Compare time value in WP_User_Query for sending emails

Tags: wp-cron, date-time, wp-user-query, comparison

I am trying to setup a custom plugin that will compare the time (last activity of a user) and send emails to them. I am using the below WP_User_Query and a cron job

```
function reminder_email() {

// Get the contributors and authors who haven't logged in for 60 days - DO I NEED TO SET UP W3C Total Cache IN SOMEWAY IN ORDER FOR THE Query TO WORK? I DONT HAVE DB OR OBJECT CACHE ENABLED
$remind_users = new WP_User_Query( [   // or new \WP_User_Query syntax?? not sure 
'role'         => [ 'contributor', 'author', ],
'meta_key'     => 'last_activity',
'meta_value'   => strtotime( '-60 days' ),   // IS THIS CORRECT? HOW TO COMPARE THE last_activity 'Y-m-d H:i:s' WITH THE LAST 60 DAYS
'meta_compare' => '<',
  ] );

if ( ! empty( $remind_users ) ) { 
foreach( $remind_users->get_results() as $user ) {
    
$message = sprintf( 'Hello %1$s,' , $user->first_name ) . "<br><br>"; 
$message .= sprintf( 'Have you forgot us? Please visit our site again.' ) ."<br>"; 

wp_mail( $user->user_email , 'Reminder Email for You', $message );
     }
    }
 }
add_action( 'reminder_email', 'reminder_email' );
```

The `last_activity` meta_key stores the time in 'Y-m-d H:i:s'.

1. Can i use the strtotime( '-60 days' ) for getting all the users that have not been active for 60 days?
2. What is the difference between `new WP_User_Query` and `new \WP_User_Query` syntax?
3. Inside the same function can i use another similar WP_User_Query to send different emails to other type of roles? So to avoid creating 2 cron jobs for this.

I have tried to do :

```
$today = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$remind_users = new WP_User_Query( [  
'role__in' => array( 'contributor', 'administrator' ),
'meta_key'     => 'last_activity',
'meta_query' => array( 
        array(
            'key' => 'last_activity',
            'value' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($today . '-60 days')),
            'compare' => '>',
            'type' => 'DATE' // Let WordPress know we're working with date
            )
        )
 ] );
```

But doesn't give me the users with last activity before 60 days ago.
What am i doing wrong here :(

Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the correct way to compare dates in a WP query\_posts meta\_query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11173/what-is-the-correct-way-to-compare-dates-in-a-wp-query-posts-meta-query)

Comment: 2. They're basically the same, see [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790020/what-does-a-backslash-do-in-php-5-3) on the topic. 3. The choice is yours, personally I'd prefer multiple small crons over one large cron that does multiple things.

Comment: Thank you @kero for your answer. I already saw thttps://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11173/what-is-the-correct-way-to-compare-dates-in-a-wp-query-posts-meta-query but i am not sure how i should set the array in my case. I made many tests but with no luck. Could you help me please?